# What are MongoManagedTypes - new in spring-data-mongodb version 4.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

In `MyMongoConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` I created a bean when using version 3.2 of spring-data-mongodb:

```
@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(MongoCustomConversions customConversions) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.mongoMappingContext(customConversions);
}
```

which needs to be changed after upgrading to version 4.0 to:

```
@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(MongoCustomConversions customConversions, MongoManagedTypes types) {
    return super.mongoMappingContext(customConversions(), types);
}
```

but this gives an error because `MongoManagedTypes` is not set. What are `MongoManagedTypes` and how do we set them?

When the beans are initialized the size of `types` is 0, and I get an error message:

```
Factory method 'mongoMappingContext' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'customConversions' defined in class path resource 
factory bean 'MyMongoConfig'; factory method 'customConversions()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
```

However, customConversion() works prior to upgrading to version 4.0

Edit: The change from not needing MongoManagedTypes to needing it was done in this commit:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/cfd55be95bf7bf70bc1fdf243209591c0b0c4d5b
in java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoConfigurationSupport.java

Related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4365